# Разбиение разделов на Linux. Минимальный размер равен текущему

Tags: linux, gparted

Возникла проблема в разбитии разделов. Пишет, что

> минимальный размер = текущему.

Можно ли как-то разбить используемый раздел ? Хочу поставить `Windows`. На разделе sda2 400ГБ и хочу из него достать 300ГБ и поменять файловую систему для того, чтобы туда поставить ОС.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

Comment: А при чем тут директории? Это разделы, вообще-то. По картинке у вас есть три раздела и неразмеченная область. А в MBR есть место для хранения информации только о 4 разделах. Вероятно, поэтому у вас что-то и не получается.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так а что сделать с неразменным ?

Comment: Ничего не делать, например.

Comment: где пишет, при какой операции пишет. чего вы хотите получить

Comment: @Mike я хочу разделить этот раздел, чтоб на него поставить Windows, но с разделами ничего нельзя сделать

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич "этот раздел" у вас в количестве трех штук, а телепаты в отпуске. Попробуйте внятно и конкретно описать что вы делаете.

Comment: но у вас на диске больше нет места под разделы, в не размеченной области только 1 Мб. вам надо удалять какой то из разделов (с потерей информации) и создавать после этого разделы заново, меньших размеров или пользоваться утилитами меняющими размеры существующих файловых систем

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я хочу поставить Windows. На разделе SDA2 400гб и хочу из него достать 300гб и поменять файловую систему для того, чтобы туда поставить ОС.

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич осталось написать это в самом вопросе...

Comment: осталось еще добавить нужна ли вам информация находящаяся в разделе

Comment: @Mike да, нужна

Comment: тогда изменяйте размер например с помощью acronis. только имейте ввиду, перед выполнением этой операции настоятельно рекомендуется сделать резервную копию всей информации. потому что ни одно средство ресайза не гарантирует на 100% что информация не будет потеряна

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое. А ещё вопрос почему только 4 раздела можно? с чем это связано ? и что если я снесу файл подкачки?

Comment: потому что MBR на диске занимает всего 1 сектор (512 байт) и в нем помимо таблицы разделов должно быть место еще и под код начального загрузчика. поэтому под информацию о разделах выделено всего 4 записи. но любая из этих записей может быть объявлена расширенной и будет указывать на другой сектор, где будет таблица еще на 4 раздела. правда я не понял почему у вас при наличии EFI и использовании parted вроде как MBR, а не GPT, где нет подобных ограничений. Свап в принципе можно удалить, только перед этим уберите его из /etc/fstab. но тогда процессы не смогут превышать размер ОЗУ

Comment: А что с прошлым советом? Почему скриншот сильно другой?

Comment: @Mike всё равно не получается изменить его, удалил файл подкачки и получилось их 3, но всё равно не получается / порезать

Comment: Что значит "порезать", gparted не умеет изменять размер используемых разделов, им можно только удалять и создавать заново. тем более, что вы его наверняка запускаете из под самой системы, а выполнить ресайз файловой системы с которой вы загрузились в принципе невозможно. Вам нужен загрузочный диск с акронисом

Comment: Не помню как gparted, но partitionmanager (kde) прекрасно умеет менять размеры раздела.

Comment: Не помню как gparted, но partitionmanager(kde) прекрасно умеет менять размеры раздела. 
Вывод, качаем Live дистр с KDE(plasma), загружаемся с него, в консоли входим в su(не sudo), стартуем partitionmanager, удаляем swap, двигаем размер корневого раздела до  нужного размера, но не меньше, чем данных на разделе!!!
Перезагружаемся уже с установочного диска/флешки win
На свободное место ставим win.
Опять перезагружаемся с Live CD/флешки, восстанавливаем загрузчик grub2.
Все.

Comment: @SeyDee восстанавливаем загрузчик grub2, а зачем это делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что изменять размер раздела - данный раздел должен быть неактивен/не примонтирован, что не возможно сделать в данном случае.

Для того что-бы изменить размер раздела в Вашем случае - необходимо загрузиться с LiveCD. Live версия доступна при загрузке с инсталяционного образа (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) выбираете "Try Ubuntu", дожидаетесь загрузки, а дальше работаете с GParted. Помните, что изменение размера раздела не гарантирует на 100%, что данные не пострадают.